# Why did my Mac restart?

Tags: macos, mojave, shutdown

I am running macOS Mojave 10.14 on a 2018 13" MacBook Pro. This morning, to my surprise it was turned off.

In `/Library⁩/Logs⁩/DiagnosticReports⁩` I see a file called `shutdown_stall_2018-10-20-113446_MattPad.shutdownStall` but I don't know how to read it.

How can I find out why it restarted?

I just noticed that the problem details being sent to Apple list:
x86 Shutdown Cause: 0x1
What does that mean?

I ran the log command to see the shutdown causes in the logs and got this:

```
log show --predicate 'eventMessage contains "Previous shutdown cause"'
Filtering the log data using "composedMessage CONTAINS "Previous shutdown cause""
Skipping info and debug messages, pass --info and/or --debug to include.
Timestamp                       Thread     Type        Activity             PID    TTL
2018-10-18 16:31:21.752378-0700 0xb4       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 5
2018-10-18 18:53:28.963132-0700 0xb8       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 1
2018-10-18 19:50:17.130199-0700 0xb5       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 1
2018-10-20 09:59:39.081932-0700 0xb6       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 1
2018-10-20 11:35:16.748688-0700 0xb6       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 1
2018-10-20 11:39:36.883727-0700 0xb5       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 1
2018-10-22 08:20:07.672163-0700 0xb6       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 5
```

According to https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/shutdown-causes/ 5 means correct shutdown, but shutdown cause: 1 is not listed.

Comment: What is the output of running `file shutdown_stall_2018-10-20-113446_MattPad.shutdownStall`?

Comment: file /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/shutdown_stall_2018-10-20-113446_MattPad.shutdownStall
/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/shutdown_stall_2018-10-20-113446_MattPad.shutdownStall: ASCII text         However it is not in a readable formate. I ran spindump -i and got readable text. I don't understand it though

Comment: Hi, I do not know if this still works in Mojave to show you the reason for Shutdown run it in Terminal  `syslog -k Sender kernel -k Message CSeq 'n Cause: -' | tail | awk '/:/{$4=""; print}' | pbcopy'

>>The output is in the clipboard

Comment: I get this:         syslog -k Sender kernel -k Message CSeq 'n Cause: -'
NOTE:  Most system logs have moved to a new logging system.  See log(1) for more information.

Comment: It looks like the new way to do that is:     log show --predicate 'eventMessage contains "Previous shutdown cause"'

Comment: On advice from apple support forum I did      sudo pmset -a standbydelay 604800      We shall see how that works.

Comment: I have a similar issue as you.  `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/ProxiedDevice-Bridge/panic-full-2019-09-09-213825.791.ips` has `x86 Shutdown Cause: 0x1` but `log show --predicate 'eventMessage contains "Previous shutdown cause"' --last 30m` has `Previous Shutdown Cause: -20`.  Unfortunately the link you provided also has no documentation for `-20`.